# How to debug a NullPointerException from lein run?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm trying to create a simple Clojure app to **parse stdin** and **execute some commands** accordingly. I created a new [leiningen](https://leiningen.org/) project with `lein new app myproject` and added my code to `src/myproject/core.clj` :

```clj
(ns myproject.core
  (:require [clojure.string :as str])
  (:gen-class))

(def global-vector (ref [{:name "Bob" :age 22} {:name "Alice" :age 21}]))

(defn call [fn_name & fn_args]
  (apply (resolve (symbol fn_name)) (map keyword fn_args)))

(defn select
  [key]
  (dosync
    (map #(get % key) @global-vector)))

(defn -main []
  (while true
    (let [[command cargs] (str/split (read-line) #" ")]
    (println (call command cargs)))))
```

To be explicit here are the steps to reproduce what I'm trying to do:

- I want to run this program from command line (currently I use `lein run`)
- It should wait for user input (I use the `read-line` function)
- I enter some text: `select name`
- I expect the program to print the names stored in `global-vector` but it crashes with a NPE instead

Everything seems to work as expected when ran with `lein repl`:

```clj
myproject.core=> (select :name)
("Bob" "Alice")
myproject.core=> (apply select [:name])
("Bob" "Alice")
myproject.core=> (call "select" "name")
("Bob" "Alice")
myproject.core=> (let [[a b] (str/split "select name" #" ")]
        #_=>     (println (call a b)))
(Bob Alice)
nil
myproject.core=> (-main)
select name
(Bob Alice)
```

But when I run it with `lein run` and enter some input I get a `NullPointerException`:

```sh
$lein run
select name
Syntax error (NullPointerException) compiling at (/private/var/folders/lt/z56f492j3f3gcdf83y4f8x2r0000gn/T/form-init2363625704485841211.clj:1:125).
null

Full report at:
/var/folders/lt/z56f492j3f3gcdf83y4f8x2r0000gn/T/clojure-6381054570172229346.edn
```

Here is the content of the report file:

```
{:clojure.main/message
 "Syntax error (NullPointerException) compiling at (/private/var/folders/lt/z56f492j3f3gcdf83y4f8x2r0000gn/T/form-init2363625704485841211.clj:1:125).\nnull\n",
 :clojure.main/triage
 {:clojure.error/phase :compile-syntax-check,
  :clojure.error/line 1,
  :clojure.error/column 125,
  :clojure.error/source "form-init2363625704485841211.clj",
  :clojure.error/path
  "/private/var/folders/lt/z56f492j3f3gcdf83y4f8x2r0000gn/T/form-init2363625704485841211.clj",
  :clojure.error/class java.lang.NullPointerException},
 :clojure.main/trace
 {:via
  [{:type clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException,
    :message
    "Syntax error compiling at (/private/var/folders/lt/z56f492j3f3gcdf83y4f8x2r0000gn/T/form-init2363625704485841211.clj:1:125).",
    :data
    {:clojure.error/phase :compile-syntax-check,
     :clojure.error/line 1,
     :clojure.error/column 125,
     :clojure.error/source
     "/private/var/folders/lt/z56f492j3f3gcdf83y4f8x2r0000gn/T/form-init2363625704485841211.clj"},
    :at [clojure.lang.Compiler load "Compiler.java" 7648]}
   {:type java.lang.NullPointerException,
    :at [clojure.core$apply invokeStatic "core.clj" 665]}],
  :trace
  [[clojure.core$apply invokeStatic "core.clj" 665]
   [clojure.core$apply invoke "core.clj" 660]
   [myproject.core$call invokeStatic "core.clj" 8]
   [myproject.core$call doInvoke "core.clj" 7]
   [clojure.lang.RestFn invoke "RestFn.java" 423]
   [myproject.core$_main invokeStatic "core.clj" 18]
   [myproject.core$_main invoke "core.clj" 15]
   [clojure.lang.Var invoke "Var.java" 380]
   [user$eval140 invokeStatic "form-init2363625704485841211.clj" 1]
   [user$eval140 invoke "form-init2363625704485841211.clj" 1]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler eval "Compiler.java" 7177]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler eval "Compiler.java" 7167]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler load "Compiler.java" 7636]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler loadFile "Compiler.java" 7574]
   [clojure.main$load_script invokeStatic "main.clj" 475]
   [clojure.main$init_opt invokeStatic "main.clj" 477]
   [clojure.main$init_opt invoke "main.clj" 477]
   [clojure.main$initialize invokeStatic "main.clj" 508]
   [clojure.main$null_opt invokeStatic "main.clj" 542]
   [clojure.main$null_opt invoke "main.clj" 539]
   [clojure.main$main invokeStatic "main.clj" 664]
   [clojure.main$main doInvoke "main.clj" 616]
   [clojure.lang.RestFn applyTo "RestFn.java" 137]
   [clojure.lang.Var applyTo "Var.java" 705]
   [clojure.main main "main.java" 40]],
  :phase :compile-syntax-check}}
```

I'm trying to understand the traceback but I lack familiarity with the Clojure/Java environment and it's indecipherable so far. What's being called on a Null value exactly? Is it because `global-vector` is defined outside of main? (But why does it work in Repl then?)

I use Clojure version: `1.10.1.739` and Leiningen `2.9.4` on Java 11.0.2 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further investigation I found that it has to do with [namespace](https://clojure.org/reference/namespaces) resolution. The following expression:

```clj
(resolve (symbol fn_name))
```

works in Repl but return `nil` when executed from "lein run", which in turn causes the apply function to raise a `NullPointerException`.

The [symbol](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/symbol) function can be passed a `ns` parameter so I fixed it by hardcoding my current namespace like this:

```clj
(resolve (symbol "myproject.core" fn_name))
```